# Android - Center Entire TextView, including background

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-background

I'm adding a textview programmatically and wish to put a background on it, but I can't seem to get the background to center. (updated)

```
  FrameLayout mTableView1 = new FrameLayout(this);
  FrameLayout mTableView2 = new FrameLayout(this);
  FrameLayout mTableView3 = new FrameLayout(this);
  int bgTop = getResources().getIdentifier("tableb1" , "drawable", this.getPackageName());
  int bgMid = getResources().getIdentifier("tableb2" , "drawable", this.getPackageName());
  int bgBot = getResources().getIdentifier("tableb3" , "drawable", this.getPackageName());
  setTextStyle(tv1, "Dashboard", Gravity.CENTER, mLayoutView, 40, getResources().getColor(R.color.white), getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent), 0, 5);
  setTextStyle(tv2, "Happening Now:", Gravity.LEFT, mLayoutView, 15, getResources().getColor(R.color.white), getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent), 0, 5);
  setTableStyle(tv3, "Mark Novak Scheduled", Gravity.CENTER, mTableView1, 20, getResources().getColor(R.color.black), getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent), 0, 0, bgTop);
  setTableStyle(tv4, "Attendance up 3%", Gravity.CENTER, mTableView2, 20, getResources().getColor(R.color.black), getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent), 0, 0, bgMid);
  setTableStyle(tv5, "Location of next event", Gravity.CENTER, mTableView3, 20, getResources().getColor(R.color.black), getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent), 0, 0, bgBot);

 mLayoutView.addView(mTableView1);
 mLayoutView.addView(mTableView2);
 mLayoutView.addView(mTableView3);
}

   private void setTextStyle(TextView tv, String s, int g, LinearLayout L, int fsize, int textColor, int backgroundColor, int lpad, int tpad){
   tv.setText(s);
   tv.setGravity(g);
   tv.setTextColor(textColor);
   tv.setTextSize(fsize);
   tv.setPadding(lpad, tpad, lpad, 0);
   L.addView(tv);
 }

    private void setTableStyle(TextView tv, String s, int g, FrameLayout L, int fsize, int textColor, int backgroundColor, int lpad, int tpad, int bg){
   tv.setText(s);
   tv.setGravity(g);
   tv.setTextColor(textColor);
   tv.setTextSize(fsize);
   tv.setPadding(lpad, 0, 0, 0);
   tv.setBackgroundResource(bg);
   tv.setWidth(200);

   L.addView(tv);
```

}

What I get is that the text is off-center 200 pixels, but the whole textview isn't. The background image stretches from one end to the other. Is there a way around this? I've tried setting the width. I had it working for a little bit, but then something went wrong and it stretched out again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post code for setTextStyle function as well?

Comment: @vipulmittal Done. It was the same one as the other function, only with an extra variable to set the background. Really, I should just make it one function and pass null off to it, I just didn't get around to it.

Comment: check my ans and let me know if it helps

Comment: @vipulmittal I did check your answer, and you set me on the right track, so I'll give you the points. Just see my comment below and modify your answer appropriately and I'll check you off and vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alien your `TextView` itself. You need to set `layout_gravity` not `gravity`.
In java you can do it by setting layout params.

For ex:

```
 private void setTextStyle(TextView tv, String s, int g, LinearLayout L, int fsize, int textColor, int backgroundColor, int lpad, int tpad){

   tv.setText(s);
   tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 25, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
   tv.setGravity(g);
   tv.setTextColor(textColor);
   tv.setTextSize(fsize);
   tv.setPadding(lpad, tpad, lpad, 0);
   L.addView(tv);
 }
```

Comment: When I do this I need to apply it to the other function, setTableStyle (as that's the one that needs centering). I also change it to FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout. This crashes the app.

Comment: if it's framelayout you need to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams and also can you post the LOGCAT

Comment: Yes, I did change it to FrameLayout.LayoutParams. It's crashing on lp.gravity=g, for the record. You want me to add the LOGCAT to the OP?

Comment: You got the closest, so you get the answer. Just remove that fourth and fifth line and replace it with: tv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 25, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));

Comment: You need to also remove tv.setGravity(g). That's the fifth line I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use linear layout to center stuff in it. use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Well, that both worked and broke the whole thing. The textview is centered properly, but now everything begins at the top with FrameLayout. Do I now need to set the y position for each item? That sounds like it could be troublesome when it comes time to test on multiple devices.

Comment: I think I'm going to try to keep it a LinearLayout and then add a FrameLayout to it. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I've updated my code, and placed the textviews inside a framelayout, then placed each of them in the linear layout. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android backgrounds always scale to match their `View`'s bounds. If you want a more advanced `ScaleType`, you'll have to use an `ImageView`.

```
 private void setTableStyle(TextView tv, String s, int g, FrameLayout L, int fsize, int textColor, int backgroundColor, int lpad, int tpad, int bg){
     tv.setText(s);
     tv.setGravity(g);
     tv.setTextColor(textColor);
     tv.setTextSize(fsize);
     tv.setPadding(lpad, 0, 0, 0);
     tv.setWidth(200); 

     ImageView bgView = new ImageView(tv.getContext);
     bgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
     bgView.setImageResource(bg);
     FrameLayout.LayoutParams flp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     flp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
     L.addView(bgView, flp);
     L.addView(tv);
}
```